# Node.js/Express Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5000

Tags: node.js, express, https

OS - Windows 10 Pro
Node.js - ver 5.9.1

Hi,

So I'm getting the above mentioned error message when running my app under nodeJS/Express.

My server/app.js file is as follows:

```html
'use strict';


// Set default node environment to development

var connectionString = config.mongo.connectionstring;

console.log("connection string : " + connectionString);
mongoose.connect(connectionString);

// Setup server
var app = express();
var httpsOptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('../server/privatekey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('../server/certificate.pem')
};
var baseAddress = 5000;
var redirectAddress = 5001;
var httpsAddress = 5002;

net.createServer(tcpConnection).listen(baseAddress);
http.createServer(httpConnection).listen(redirectAddress);
https.createServer(httpsOptions, httpsConnection).listen(httpsAddress);

function tcpConnection(conn) {
    conn.once('data', function (buf) {
        // A TLS handshake record starts with byte 22.
        var address = (buf[0] === 22) ? httpsAddress : redirectAddress;
        var proxy = net.createConnection(address, function () {
            proxy.write(buf);
            conn.pipe(proxy).pipe(conn);
        });
    });
}

function httpConnection(req, res) {
    var host = req.headers['host'];
    res.writeHead(301, { "Location": "https://" + host + req.url });
    res.end();
}

function httpsConnection(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Length': '5' });
    res.end('HTTPS');
}

// Expose app
exports = module.exports = app;
```

What am I overlooking here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to connect to port `5000` while your application listens on port `3000`.